# C# Windows Service Unable to Connect to MySQL

Tags: c#, service

I wrote a windows forms app that connects to a MYSQL database, it ran on my server fine, I've tried to make it a service but now my service is unable to connect to the Mysql. Its the actual connection that is it unable to make.

```
server = "127.0.0.1";
database = "blah_dbname";
uid = "blah_uid";
password = "blah_password";
string connectionString = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" + database + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";SslMode=none";
connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
```

Like I said in the windows forms app the 'new MySqlConnection' line works fine, but fails in the windows service.

Anyone any suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had a similar problem, the problem was that we realized that the driver that used the service was different from the one in the application, one works with the driver configuration of 32 Windows (x86, 32-bit) and the other Windows (x86, 64-bit).

I would check the driver.